# Why is it that $9w^2 ≡ 0 \pmod 4$ when $w>0$ is even?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is it that $9w^2 ≡ 0 \pmod 4$ when $w > 0$ is even?

Say $w=2$; then you have $36 ≡ 0 \pmod 4$.

The same thing if $w=6$; then you have $ 324 ≡ 0 \mod 4$.

I dont see why, because $9 ≡ 1 \pmod 4$, and if we work with $w^2$ then we get $w^2≡ 0 \pmod 4$.

I am guessing it works because $1 \cdot 0 ≡ 0 \pmod 4$ but why do we treat it as regular multiplication?

Comment: I don't understand your question; since $9 = 9 \cdot 1^2$, that's a case where $w$ is not even. It's also worth mentioning that $9 w^2 \equiv w^2 \mod 4$, which is zero *if and only if* $w$ is even.

Comment: but $1$ is not even? How about why is $9w^2≡w^2 \mod 4 $ , which is zero if and only if $w$ is even? like what is the reason behind that?

Comment: Since $1$ is not even, it's not (apparently) relevant to your question about what happens *when* $w$ is even. For the second question, $w^2$ is divisible by $4$ if and only if $w$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: $w$ doesn't have to be positive. It works for all $w\in\Bbb Z$. We have $9w^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}\iff w$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $w$ is even, it can be written as $2k$ for some integer $k$.

Then $9w^2=36k^2=4\times 9k^2$ is a multiple of $4$ and is equivalent to $0$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $ab\bmod c=(a\bmod c)(b\bmod c)$, provided you take the modulo of the RHS.

Indeed,

$$(a+kc)(b+kc)=ab+c(ak+bk+k^2c),$$ and the two products coincide, modulo $c$.

The same holds with addition, $(a+b)\bmod c=(a\bmod c)+(b\bmod c)$, provided...